# I need wallpapers from a newer release!

Tags: desktop-background

I am running ubuntu 14.04 on an HP Compaq 6715b with an AMD Turion x2. I want the wallpapers from 15.04 and 15.10. How do I get the wallpapers into the computer wallpaper folder (usr/doc)?

Comment: Search the web and download

Answer (score 2):

I dont have a Ubuntu Machine right now. But try this

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-wallpapers
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/09/ubuntu-15-10-wily-werewolf-default-wallpaper

as these were just wallpapers package you can install it with out any dependencies issues.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the source used to build the wallpaper packages and build them yourself:

```
sudo apt-get install bzr
sudo apt-get build-dep ubuntu-wallpapers
bzr branch lp:ubuntu-wallpapers
cd ubuntu-wallpapers
bzr builddeb -- -us -uc
sudo dpkg -i ../ubuntu-wallpapers*.deb
```

`bzr` (Bazaar) is the standard version control tool for Ubuntu, and `bzr builddeb` offers a convenient way to build packages from Ubuntu.

As a side effect, the `ubuntu-wallpapers` directory just created will have all the wallpapers.

Comment: If this is the answer, please choose it as the answer as it is more detailed and explainative.