# How to find a certain wallpaper

Tags: desktop-background

I am looking for one specific wallpaper that I'm sure is from either Ubuntu (Wily/Unity) or Enlightenment (e20). I've had this combination of Ubuntu/e20 for about half a year before switching to Bodhi. (It might have been e19, not 100% sure anymore.) Everything's fine, except ... I loved that one wallpaper, but I can't seem to find it again.

The picture was a horizonless close-up of a piece of rock, really just the surface. Its colour was a dark brown that was almost red, like the stone was rich in iron, and it seemed have a raw surface, similar to sandstone. Iron ore maybe?

I downloaded at least 20 Ubuntu wallpaper packages that didn't sound too esoteric, I looked up e17-stuff.com, and I ran several search engines on a dozen different combinations of the wallpaper's theme. But seeing the number of Iron Man, kitschy zen art and rock music fans out there, googling for [[iron, stone, red, rock] free] wallpaper gave very different results than what I was hoping for.

How can I find that picture? If it was not Ubuntu, but Enlightenment, where can I find out which packages/picture sources they use?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/11447/where-can-i-find-all-the-wallpapers-ever-included

Comment: Thanks parto, unfortunately it only goes through 10.10/Meerkat.

Comment: I have started a bounty for the question. Check it out later, it should be updated.

Comment: Try: http://askubuntu.com/a/712254/158442

Comment: So, I just downloaded the package as the other person in the thread suggested, and it wasn't in there. This tells me that it really must have been an enlightenment package. I more or less cloned this question to the Bodhi/Enlightenment forum http://forums.bodhilinux.com/index.php?/topic/13219-how-to-find-a-certain-wallpaper/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was indeed an enlightenment wallpaper. [In the Bodhi forums](http://forums.bodhilinux.com/index.php?/topic/13219-how-to-find-a-certain-wallpaper/#entry97649), someone found it in /usr/share/enlightenment/data/backgrounds/Brown_Rock_Hi.edj